# Python 3.x - Bokeh - RadioButtonGroup callback

Tags: python, radio-button, data-visualization, bokeh

*Note from Maintainers: This questions concerns "Python" CustomJS callbacks, described in the link below, which will be removed in Bokeh 2.0*

---

Bokeh demonstration shows how to add a callback to a slider button - 
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-with-a-python-function

I am trying to create a similar callback for a radio button group -

```
radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["literacy", "economy", "health","household"], active=0,callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(callback) )
```

But the above code gives an error -

```
AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'callback' to RadioButtonGroup, possible attributes are active, disabled, labels, name, tags or type
```

So does Bokeh support callback from radio button group or are callbacks possible only from slider button as shown in the documentation?

Comment: Getting the same error for `ResetTool`, on Python 2.7.12 and Bokeh 0.12. Also tried `reset = ResetTool(); reset.callback = CustomJS.from_py_func(callback)`.

Answer (score 1):

the different widgets have different attributes which contain the selected/highlighted values. For a `RadioButtonGroup` that is `active`, for a `slider` it is `value`

You will have to change the `callback` function accordingly

```
def callback(source=source):
    data = source.data
    f = cb_obj.active  # instead of 'value'
    x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
    source.change.emit()
```